# How to horizontally align text in tables?

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

I seek to horizontally align unicode equivalence symbols, which derail when resized: https://jsfiddle.net/r6bxgem3/26/

Tried `vertical-align:middle` to no avail. Current vs. intended:

[image]

Any resolutions? Help's appreciated.

```css
.arr {color: red; font-size: 200%; }
.lft {float: right; display: inline;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" async src=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js?config=
TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
<table><tr><td><span class="lft">
    
\(1+3+2\ \)                                                         
</span></td><td><span class="arr">&#11020;</span></td><td>
\(\ 6+2-2\)                                                           
</td></tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT:** Increased resize to emphasize vertical derailment. Added explanatory image.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are we see the problem in this snippet? What is the expected result?

Comment: Yeah, the snippet looks fine to me as well. How do you want it to look?

Comment: It's vertically derailed; see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the `line-height: 100%`:

```css
.arr {color: red; font-size: 200%; line-height: 100%}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" async src=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js?config=
TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="lft">\(1+3+2\ \)</span></td>
    <td><span class="arr">&#11020;</span></td>
    <td>\(\ 6+2-2\)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As a side note, you can omit other rules and even `span` *elements*, since their presence has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Add following css to fix this

```
span {
line-height: 50px;
}
```

```css
span {
line-height: 50px;
}
.arr {color: red; font-size: 200%; }
.lft {float: right; display: inline;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" async src=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js?config=
TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
<table><tr><td><span class="lft">
    
\(1+3+2\ \)                                                         
</span></td><td><span class="arr">&#11020;</span></td><td>
\(\ 6+2-2\)                                                           
</td></tr>
</table>
```

and please read this  https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align

Answer (score -1):

You were close. Try to put this in your CSS file.

```
td 
{
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center; 
}
```